# iOS Swift change image with orientation on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, interface-builder, screen-orientation

I have an `iOS` application that should run on both portrait and landscape modes. The problem is that I have an image that should be changed on every orientation, i.e. the portrait image is different than the landscape one.

I have successfully implemented this for `iPhone` screens from Interface Builder. But for `iPad`, the problem is that the size class for `iPad` is always `Regular width` and `Regular Height`. So I can't differentiate between them from `Interface Builder.`

So, I implemented it programmatically:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification,
                                           object: nil,
                                           queue: .main,
                                           using: { notification in
                                            //change image for iPad here
    })
```

and I call the method that checks for orientation and sets the image when the view is loaded, so that it sets the correct image.

The problem now is that if this method is called from `viewDidLoad`, it doesn't change the `UIImageView`'s image since it is not created yet. When called from `viewDidAppear`, it changes the image correctly but this change is reflected on the view and the user can see it while changing.

My question is:
Is there any way to set image for `iPad` based on size class from `Interface Builder`?

and if not, how can I solve the problem of live image changing while doing this programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Since size classes on iPad won't changed you can work with device orientation

**SWIFT 4**

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad &&
   UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {
      // do something here
   }
```

Comment: This is the current solution I use. It works. But when I call this in viewDidLoad, it doesn't change the image. When called from viewDidAppear, it changes it BUT the change is noticed by the user - since it is changed after it has appeared on the screen.

Comment: @AmaniElsaed try to call it from viewWillAppear(). I'm not sure but give it a try :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Same result as viewDidLoad

Comment: Huh... I can't say anything else then :(